# Pass a parameter into collection select method for text_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
  <%= collection_select(:catgory, :id, @categories, :id, :title, {}, data: { behavior: 'category_dropdown' }) %>
```

In the above code I need to pass a parameter to the title method.  Is there any way to do this with collection_select?

```
  <%= collection_select(:catgory, :id, @categories, :id, (:title, @program), {}, data: { behavior: 'category_dropdown' }) %>
```

Edit:
Looking at the internals for collection_select the text_method. It is eventually passed to a .send method which should allow for element.send(:title, @program).  However, I think the issue why I still can't pass the param is that collection select is reading (:title, @program) as two params instead of one.

Comment: Do you have access to @program within your Category model?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a has_many relationship so I need to pass the program to know which program to put in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select` instead:

```
select "catgory", "id", @categories.map{|c| [c.title(@program), c.id]}, {}, data: { behavior: 'category_dropdown' }
```

Should be working.

Comment: No problem.  I'm just glad to have a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `collection_select` if your model has an existing parameter you can overwrite:

```
f.collection_select( :your_model_id, 
  YourModel.all.map{|ym| ym.name = ym.custom_name(your_parameter); ym}, 
  :id, :name, 
  {:selected => @model_instance.logic}, 
  {:class => 'your class', :other => "..." } )
```

For instance I do this to conditionally pluralize my model's `name` attribute

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  DEFAULT_NAME_COUNT = 99

  def pluralized_name(n = DEFAULT_NAME_COUNT)
    begin
      return name.pluralize(n)
    rescue
    end

    name
  end
end
```